# How to Access Nested Directory Files in Bazel Go Test Environment?

Tags: go, bazel, bazel-rules

I'm working with a Go monorepo and using Bazel. My issue arises when trying to access Go files located in a nested directory structure during testing.

The project has a directory structure like this:

```
/src/
  /monorepo/
    /subproject/
      /component/
        /nested/
          /directory/
            - somefile.go
            - anotherfile.go
        /test/
          - test.go
          - BUILD.bazel
        BUILD.bazel
```

In the nested/directory/BUILD.bazel, I have a filegroup that encompasses all Go files within that directory:

```
filegroup(
    name = "source_files",
    srcs = glob(["**/*.go"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

The test.go located in the test directory should access these Go files for testing. The relevant BUILD.bazel for the test is configured as follows:

```
go_test(
    name = "my_test",
    srcs = ["test.go"],
    data = ["//monorepo/subproject/component/nested/directory:source_files"],
    embed = [":component_lib"],
    deps = [
        # Other dependencies...
    ],
)
```

Despite this setup, during test execution with Bazel, the files/folder in nested/directory are not found, resulting in file not found errors. It seems Bazel is not making these files available in the test's sandbox environment.

How can I correctly configure Bazel so that the Go test can access these files? Is there a specific method to reference and utilize these nested directory files within the test environment?

Tried various approaches via Genrule too. But that didn't work either. However, I am able to expose files from a config/ directory to tests via the similar filegroup glob definition. One this to call out, the `/directory/` contains `go.mod` and `main.go` in it. Not sure if that can cause problems as `/component/` has its own `main.go`.

Answer (score 0):

To see if the files are in the sandbox, run with `--sandbox_debug`, which will print the sandbox directory and leave it. (Be aware that this will leave large amounts of temporary files if you run large and/or repeated builds with it.)

I suspect your files are in the sandbox, but you're having trouble finding them. rules_go has a [runfiles package](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/tree/master/go/runfiles) designed for this. You may also be able to locate them with relative paths, although that's not as robust to changes in how the data files are being generated.

Comment: Sandbox debug says `BUILD file not found in any of the following directories. Add a BUILD file to a directory to mark it as a package.` while i have a `BUILD.bazel` defined in it with the filegroup.